# Two errors in Web.config ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

so firstly, I get this error when publishing my web application:

> "System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed."

So it is said that I'm supposed to write the following code in my Web.config:

```
<trustLevel name="Full">
```

So I did, but then, I got this error:

> "This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using  from an inherited configuration file."

At it has to apparently have to do with the machine.config (which I cannot find)...

Does anyone have a proper solution for this?

Regards,

Comment: This looks like your application's security context is already restricted (which is why you can't elevate them with `<trustLevel>`). You'll have to speak with your sysadmin to request higher privileges for your application. That said, what task are you doing that requires full-trust?

Comment: There is no system administrator, Iam my own website. All my other tabs works just fine, it just this new one I recently created which wont open.

Comment: You didn't fully address Dai's comment. *what task are you doing that requires full trust?*

Comment: What do you mean with task? It does not matter which level of trust I use, I used them all, but I get the same error.

Comment: @Cleon What do browser-tabs have to do with ASP.NET? What task is your application code doing that requires full-trust?